# How to connect to a torrent tracker running on a local host?

Tags: linux, networking, ip, nat, bittorrent

I want to share huge files via bitTorrent.

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. I've set up a tracker opentracker listening to port **6969**, and a client kTorrent listening to port **6881**. My network uses NAT. I create a .torrent file, set the tracker as **http://[external_ip]:6969/announce**, the client tries to connect to it and shows "Could not connect to host localhost" message. If I use local ip (192.168.1.2) I can connect to the tracker, but other peers see my ip as 192.168.1.2.

If all clients are inside the same LAN they manage to share files this way. Port forwarding works fine, the tracker is reachable from the outside.
I don't have a router that supports NAT loopback, but I'm looking for some workaround to do the same thing with software.